# CKEditor Not Showing ToolBar in IE

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor to show some information.It is working fine in chrome and firefox.But in IE it is not showing toolbar.It is showing as:

[image]

Please Help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to CKEditor4 the toolbar displayed ok in IE8, however half of the buttons did not display at all in FF.  I cleared the cache and that fixed the problem. Might just be the same problem you are having.